# having issues with getline(cin) to array

Tags: c++

This code is part of an assignment I am working on but I can't figure out why the getline keeps returning a "no instance of overloaded function" error. I included the relevant code here and the line is towards the bottom. Any help getting "name" in to animals[i].d would be appreciated as I'm sure it's something simple. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream> // provides access to cin and cout
#include  <array>// provides access to std:array
#include <string> // required for getline

//--end of #include files-----------
//----------------------------------

using namespace std;
//----------------------------------

//**begin global constants**********
const int arraySize = 4; // **there is a subtle bug here (needs "const")
enum MyEnum // Needs to be before the struct that uses it
{
    Dog, Cat, Fish, Squirrel
};

struct MyStruct
{
    int a;
    float b;
    string c;
    MyEnum d;
};

//--end of global constants---------
//----------------------------------


//**begin main program**************
int main()
{
    // Initialization
    char myCString[arraySize] = { 0 };
    char myOtherCString[] = { "Yet another string" };
    int myInt[4] = { 27, 39, 0, 42 };
    string myString;
    MyStruct aStruct = { 4,3.5,"Dog", Dog};
    int x;
    int * pX;
    pX = &x;
    array <MyStruct, arraySize> Animals;
    // Storing values in uninitialized variables
    myCString[0] = 'A';
    myString = "A third string";
    x = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++)
    {
        Animals[i].a = rand() % 10;
        Animals[i].b = rand() % 100 / 100.0;
        Animals[i].c = MyEnum(rand() % 4);
        cout << "Enter a name: ";
        getline(cin, Animals[i].d);
    }
```

Comment: I think typo mistake here .Animals[i].d = MyEnum(rand() % 4);
        cout << "Enter a name: ";
        getline(cin, Animals[i].c);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to `std::string::getline()` needs to be a `std::string`, but you're giving it a `MyEnum` instead.

If you want to read a `std::string` and store a `MyEnum` you need to have a lookup table to convert from one to the other.

**EDIT**: Actually you've just got `c` and `d` wrong way round, haven't you?
You want to assign a random number to `d`, and the string you read with `getline()` to `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You using wrong parametters of function `getline`. `MyEnum` is not `string`. Use on of this:

```
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str, char delim);
istream& getline (istream&  is, string& str);
istream& getline (istream&& is, string& str);
```